# PHP: How to copy records from one table to another BUT it has to copy upto a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch SUM(WeightKgs) column and sum up each field to <=2000. Once it gets close to 2000, it should then save it in the database table with a common ID (to fetch for future query). Once it saved in the database, it then continues to fetch the next row   and sum up to <= 2000. This process is required to do till the last row.

I tried few while loops and for and for each loops but cant get my head around.

screenshot:

[image]

PHP code

```
       <?php

  $total = 0;
  $getValue = 0;
  $end = 2000;
   do { 
      $start = $row_GenRunRS['SUM(WeightKgs)'] ;
      $getValue = $start + $total;

      echo  $row_GenRunRS['SUM(WeightKgs)'].  " + ". $total ." = " . $getValue . " <br>";
      $total = $start + $total ;
      echo "<br> <hr><br>";
     // echo    " Start ". $start. " <br>";



  } while ($row_GenRunRS = mysql_fetch_assoc($GenRunRS)); 

  echo "Total now = " .$total;

  ?>
```

Output[image]

Comment: You can try if else inside while loop. That should do the trick. I guess

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried, it makes it easier to offer suggestions. (It's guesswork otherwise)

Comment: @KunalParekh, I tried if else in the loop but it didnt work. Is there any other way you can guide?? Thanks

Comment: @NigelRen I have just updated my image and the code, at the moment I am not using insert query at the moment, and truing to work without it. It it worked then, i will insert the sql

Comment: Please have a look over [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `for()` loop isn't very easy to understand (IMHO) and would be better as some form of `while()` loop.  But looks as though your end condition is incorrect - should it be `$total <= 2000`

Comment: @NigelRen , is Just made a change to my loop. Please have a look up in my question above. I am not entering 2000 at the moment. Just running it to see the output.

Comment: @NigelRen . I got something to work that calculates each row fetched. Just updated in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've asked for, the answer is something like this.
However, still I'm not entirely sure I've understand what you need to do.

```
<?php
        $total_weight = 0;    
        while($row_GenRunRS = mysql_fetch_assoc($GenRunRS)) {

            $total_weight = $row_GenRunRS['SUM(WeightKgs)'] + $total_weight ;
            echo "Total is: $total_weight <br><br>";   

            if($total_weight >= 2000) {
                echo "This is what you have to save: $total_weight <br><br>";
                $total_weight = 0;
            }
        }
?>
```

**Edit:**
This code will give you results close to 2000 but most of them will be greater than 2000. If you need to have all the values bellow 2000, then you have to save the total weight before you add the package which make it bigger than 2000.

```
<?php

    $total_weight = 0;    
    do {

        if($row_GenRunRS['SUM(WeightKgs)'] + $total_weight >= 2000) {
            echo "This is what you have to save: $total_weight <br><br>";
            $total_weight = 0;
        }

        $total_weight = $row_GenRunRS['SUM(WeightKgs)'] + $total_weight ;
        echo "Total is: $total_weight <br><br>";   

    } while($row_GenRunRS = mysql_fetch_assoc($GenRunRS));

    echo "This is the last package that you also have to save: $total_weight <br><br>";

?>
```

Comment: Hi Angelo, thanks for your response. Its nearly there. really close. I just had to change it to do - while loop as the first record according to while was not fetching right. but with do it has.

Comment: Hey Angelo, I am getting some value >2000. I tried with nested if but didnt work. Can you please guide me. thanks

Comment: I have uploaded my screenshot as well